# DialogFragment conflict with gesture navigation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Fullscreen Dialogfragment with a button in bottom-most part of the screen. In one plus 7 pro with gesture navigation enabled when we touch the lower-middle part of the "continue" button, the entire UI gets stuck other then toolbar. Navigation and everything still works.

[image]

Also when we click the button in bottom-middle part, the listener always triggers, so button click is happening, and if we minimize the app and reopen everything will start working again.

Style:-

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle1" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/veryDarkBlue
    </item>

    <!-- Set this to true if you want Full Screen without status bar -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

    <!-- This is important! Don't forget to set window background -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>


    <!-- Additionally if you want animations when dialog opening -->
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

Xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/pure_white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pure_white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/calendar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_toolbar">

        <mobi.hubbler.app.views.SemiBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hubbler_text_large"
            android:text="@string/date_time_select" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@color/slot_selection_divider_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calendar" />

<mobi.hubbler.app.views.BoldTextView
    android:id="@+id/timeSlotTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_spacing_bw_views"
    android:text="Time Slot"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline6" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/time_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timeSlotTitle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/submitButton"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/time_select_item" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/workflow_action_bg"
    android:text="@string/continue_text"
    android:textColor="@color/pure_white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "entire UI gets stuck"? Do you mean `DialogFragment` gets dismissed?

Comment: No, the UI will become unresponsive other then Toolbar which is also part of the DialogFragment, we do get the listener trigger when we press the button where we are calling dismiss(), but nothing happens. After we press home and reopen the dialogue will be dismissed.

Comment: Need the XML for further inspection. Did you check on other Devices?

Comment: Well, I tried 4-5 devices and IMO it's happening only in curved display devices

Comment: @puspaksaha Have added the xml

Answer (score 4):

[WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html) tell the app where the system UI appears on top of your content, along with which regions of the screen System Gestures take priority over in-app gestures. Insets are represented by the WindowInsets class and [WindowInsetsCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat) class in [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).You can use WindowInsetsCompat to have consistent behavior across all API levels.

System insets and mandatory system insets
The following inset APIs are the most commonly used inset types:

**System window insets**: They tell you where the system UI is displayed over your app. We discuss how you can use system insets to move your controls away from the system bars.

**System gesture insets**: They return all gesture areas. Any in-app swipe controls in these regions can accidentally trigger System Gestures.

**Mandatory gesture insets**: They are a subset of the system gesture insets and can't be overridden. They tell you the areas of the screen where the behavior of the System Gestures will always take priority over in-app gestures.

Also, you can see [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-gesture-conflicts-8ee9c2665c69) article.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the article, seems right, will accept once I fix it.Thanks

Comment: I tried all the options related to insets , but no help will be posting the entire XML along with style